# How to persist data between steps in angular

Tags: angular

I have an angular multi step form(6 or 7 steps) where the user will be able to fill the form once they login.
The User may fill a couple of steps and logout/close browser and come back later
When the user logs back in later on the same or different device, he should be able to continue the form rather than starting from step 1.
whether user is filling the new form or came back to fill the remaining form, on clicking the back button, data of the previous step should be persisted

local storage may not be a good idea. If the user is in an internet cafe,it could be a security breach.
Is storing in memory a better idea? if so, how to store in memory?

How can we persist the data between steps? how to store data in memory so data can be persisted?
how to save the form at every step of angular multi step form? Is it really necessary to store data to database at every step?

I am thinking to identify the browser close/tab close/session timeout/logout on a device and save all the information filled in by the user, preventing database calls on every step. For back button to work, store the data in a service as I go along the steps and retrieve from it when needed.

Comment: I would say that a good solution would be to save data to database on each step. That way the user has access to the data on every device he logs in.

Comment: There are many reasons not to use local storage and you are right to be wary of it. Kevin's suggestion is robust.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with angular services, you can create the property data in the service with a method to manipolate the datas, in you components can invoke the method or data with dependecy injection, the data stay in memory until refresh the page or close It.
You can read a service guide in angular doc
https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Answer (score 0):

Given an average of 5 fields for each step, there is more probability for users to take more than 1 session to complete all 6 or 7 steps. You can persist data in a service between steps and can persist in database when leaving the form steps. @HostListener('window:beforeunload') can be used to capture tab/window close. CanDeactivate can be used to detect navigation.